# Suse Linux 8.0 Download

Tags: linux-distributions, suse

A coworker has a server that is being moved, currently running SuSE Linux 8.0 (i386).

```
~ # uname -a
Linux lvls 2.4.18-4GB s1 Wed Mar 27 13:57:05 UTC 2002 i686 unknown
```

They tried transferring it to SuSE 8.2 (the earliest version they could find) but it failed; something about a problem with virtualization. They were unable to find a copy of SuSE 8.0 anywhere... nor was I. Is someone aware of where we can find this version of SuSE still? We are transitioning away from this ancient box, but can't just drop it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://old-en.opensuse.org/Mirrors_Discontinued_Releases#SUSE_Linux_8.0